# Decision table x/y/z/foo.xls is in folder x/y/z but declares package 'Import'

Tags: drools, kie

```
I've got a simple decision table, like so:
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|RuleSet   |x.y.z            |        |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|Import    |x.y.z.SomeClass  |        |
|RuleTable |theRules         |        |
|Name      | Condition       | Action |
|...       |                 |        |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

When I import this into Business Central, I get this warning:

```
File  'x/y/z/foo.xls' is in folder 'x/y/z' but declares package 'Import'
```

If I build a kjar and use that in a Java program, I get the same warning.

Everything works fine, but I don't understand this warning. Is there something wrong in the layout of the decision table?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer, im having the same problem in Drools 7.32.0.FINAL. For some reason drools thinks the package name is Import but it should look at the Ruleset attribute according to the docs (http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/getting-started-with-decision-tables-in-drools):
- RuleSet: The package name for the generated DRL file. Must be First entry in the Decision Table. If I change the value import to the correct package it then logs the same warning as before but now he thinks "Name" is the package :)

Comment: I'm sorry, we abandoned that POC, and apparently I wiped all that off my computer. If I archived it, I can't find it.